# I need help in rewiring a chicken coop pop door

Tags: relay, wiring, actuator, photosensor

4 years ago I purchased an automatic chicken pop door for my coop. It is 12 volts and the door opens at dawn and shuts at dusk by means of a photosensor. It is a home built device that works quite well. It stopped working recently. Of course, I took it apart to diagnose the problem and made a sketch where all the wires went (they are all either red or white) and promptly lost the sketch. I need help in correctly wiring the linear actuator to the relay. Can someone tell me how to wire this? Sorry for the primitive sketch. The linear actuator is from a hospital bed and stops when it is fully extended or fully retracted. When the polarity is reversed the actuator travels in the opposite direction. The microswitch is at the bottom of the door to stop travel when an obstruction is hit and signals that the next direction of travel is in the opposite direction. The relay is an Omron LY2N-J DPDT on a PTF08A base. The wiring shown I KNOW to be correct. I just do not know where to attach the switch (possibly 1 and 4) or the actuator.

[image]

It is important to me - I know I look like a rube - I'm not electronically oriented but can handle the wiring.

Comment: So, hi! You should probably elaborate on what the whole purpose of the (re)wiring is? I can't infer from the drawing.

Comment: Hi Marcus - I am not rewiring it. I unwired it to check the individual components and can't remember where the actuator and the microswitch get wired to the relay base to make it work.

Comment: 1) What is the photo cell? 2) what does the switch do exactly.... does the door fully open or just bounce up and down on the chicken's neck?

Comment: I purchased the door from someone else. I have contacted them and they do not have a schematic or wiring diagram. I just need help in where to attach the actuator and the micro switch.

Comment: Trevor - All that information is in my write up. Never the less: The photo cell has three leads - Line, Load and Neutral. THe photo actuates the circuit at dusk and dawn. The switch interrupts the downward stroke of the door in case an obstruction is encountered on the downward stroke (like a chicken). AND the switch tells the circuit that the next cycle is UP not down. The door closes fully at dusk and opens fully at dawn. It does not bounce up and down.

Comment: Yes I'm having issue with your description "AND the switch tells the circuit that the next cycle is UP not down." Does that imply it just stops, or does it fully open again immediately, like a garage door.

Comment: IS there  a spring involved so the actuator is not powered in the up position or a second switch?

Comment: The switch is at the bottom of the door. Downward travel of the door stops when the switch is activated. The door is rectangular and has a loose, spring loaded bottom to which the switch is attached. Any time the switch is activated on downward travel only, the door stops where it is, either on the obstruction or at the bottom of the cycle and it switches the relay so that polarity is reversed in the circuit. The next cycle, which, through the photo sensor, will be at dawn - is up. It is a boring 3 minutes, but here is a video of the operation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM8_4VTt-iI

Comment: Where is the spring and switch ? attached to door at bottom or top? and is it a simple SPST switch?  How does obstruction or door stop activate the switch close or open or toggle SPDT? SO it never retracts on an obstruction and tries again? leaving it half open?

Comment: Tony - switch is attached only at the bottom. DPDT although only two terminals are used, not three. I appreciate all you patience. I can see that a verbal description is not as thorough as I would like.

Comment: Ah..so the switch pauses the door...

Comment: So Linear Motor has internal relay too?

Comment: Then the loosely spring coupled switch is burnt out? because it has to carry the load of the motor.

Comment: not labeling the wires and not checking out the contact resistance of the switches and relays is where you screwed up.

Comment: Oh, I know I screwed up. I violated the first rule of taking something apart. Label everything, take pictures and make copies of sketches. I screwed up - that's why I came here! Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work for you. You may have to switch the motor wires around to find the right polarity though.

If there is an obstruction the relay will flip back and cause the thing to reverse till the switch clears then it will re-engage and should continue to try to close. Relay may buzz a bit though if the obstruction remains, significantly reducing the life of the relay. But I can't see any better solution with the minimal parts you have indicated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3fsDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**This may be a better solution.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdzABJ.png)</sup>

Here the switch opening stops the motor going down and it will stay there till either the obstruction is removed or it gets light and the door opens.

**UPDATE:** According to your video it's probably the second circuit.. minus the diode. Video does not show what happens when it gets light when obstructed, but I am guessing it just stays stuck. So adding a diode actually makes it better :)

Comment: I agree but something is missing in the description of the question. Is it always powered during daylight in the up position.  Is a chicken considered an obstruction.  Otherwise it is a Chicken Poop Cop Door.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ya the motor has it's own internal switches at the travel ends. SO yes it's powered at the terminals continuously.

Comment: so it has its own set reset relay

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yup that's how I understand it, or more likely two limit switches and diodes.

Comment: When the light is applied to the photo sensor the door travels up. When light is removed from the photo sensor (ie. Dark) the door travels down. Ideally I should not need to add any components - although you all are the experts and can probably make it better! I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Yes @Gus I worked on the assumption the sensor goes high voltage out when lit. If it's the other way around you would need to reverse the motor terminals and that diode if you decide to add it. It is optional assuming you visit your coop daily to make sure the door is open.

Comment: @Trevor_G There is no need for a diode at all. And it seems that the maker is using an actual linear actuator that has built in limit switches. However they may be Implemented with diodes or not. I know I am very late to this party but I just had to show how it most likely would have been done or done to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Why? Why am I alway soo late to the party!!!?? LOL

This is the circuit that would have most likely been used. When polarity is reversed back to the relays off state, is the only time the lower switch is involved. So when the solar cell tells the relay to activate the power goes directly to the motor.

If this is a Dusk Till Dawn photocell then switch connections 2 and 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxyIv7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>